# What is the Action/NotAction in a custom role to restrict Azure Policy add/change/delete to a resource group?

Tags: azure

I would like to create a Azure custom role which restricts a user to add/change/delete the policies that are attached to a resource group. Something like the owner role but without the right to manage the policies that are attached to the resource group.

I had a look at all the Actions/NotActions at [[1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/resource-provider-operations)] but did not find any that seems to match.

Does anyone know which action I have to restrict?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

these operations are:

```
Microsoft.Authorization/policyAssignments/write 
Microsoft.Authorization/policyAssignments/delete
```

Comment: the person is asking what RP operations govern policy assignments, here's the operation he needs.

Comment: Thank you, these were exactly the operations I was looking for.